# Why is my checkbox not displaying in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to display a checkbox when the `add` button is clicked but it refuses to display. Take a look at the addTask() function and you will see what I am trying to do. Thank you, in advance!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './Login.jsx';
import './Navbar.jsx';

class MainPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="main-container">
                    <h1 style={{textDecoration:'underline'}}>Tasks</h1>
                    <div className="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" id="task" className="form-control" placeholder="New Task"/>
                        <div className="input-group-append">
                            <button id="btn" className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.addTask()}>Add</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    addTask() {
        var tasks = document.getElementById('task');
        localStorage.setItem('user-task', tasks);

        return(
            <input type="checkbox" label={localStorage.getItem('user-task')} />
        )
    }

}

export default MainPage;
```

Comment: And where do you expect it to be rendered? Above the button? Below the button? You're returning the checkbox from the onClick handler, so it does nothing. You have to render it in the component tree.

Comment: I need the checkbox along with the checkbox label to be displayed underneath the entry bar. If that is possible